# How is the xml file stored in shared preferences in android

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences

I would like to know how xml files are written to disk. I know editor.putString() is used to temporarily store the key-value, and editor.apply() is used to store it to memory. So, what exactly happens behind the code to store the data on to disk, when apply() or commit() is called? What all packages and functions are called? is it finally going to the native code?

Comment: SharedPreferences is just a file in your app that all data that you fore example  putString to save will go there. and you can even go through the file as the developer and take a look at it

Comment: The default shared preferences key-value pairs are stored in an .xml file in a subdirectory of getFilesDir(). For instance `/data/user/0/<packagename>/files/shared_prefs/<packagename>_preferences.xml`.